# Who are allowed to take short positions in WTI CRUDE Oil futures?

Tags: stocks, futures, derivatives

Can any individual like me take short position?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if you can find a broker that will trade futures, you can take either a short or long position. You will most likely have to use a margin account and mark-to-market (adding funds if you're losing money) whether you go short or long.

Note that "shorting" futures is actually *simpler* than shorting, say, stocks or bonds, since you don't have to "borrow and sell" the underlying asset to go short. You just take the short side of a futures contract with another party.

Comment: Since the settlement is physical type ,then what happens if I lose the betting due to increase in price.Do I have to deliver if I don't square off my position?How does it work

Comment: Yes if you don't close your position you'll have to deliver oil, which is why many retail brokers "auto-close" futures positions close to settlement.

Comment: But I don't own crude oil .So how do I deliver?

Comment: You don't - you'd _have_ to buy to close your position before expiry or work out something with the other counterparty. This is again why most brokers auto-close positions close to expiry, so you don't get stuck in this position.

Comment: So when Oil futures price went negative it was because traders didn't want any physical delivery of crude oil as storage costs were too much .If brokers auto close their positions then why price went negative?Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: There were virtually no _buyers_ of oil contracts at that time, so those that were pressured to sell to close had to actually _pay_ to close them (hence a negative price). It would be like you trying to sell a grenade with the pin pulled.

Comment: "auto-close" just means that the broker sells to close for you at market prices - it does _not_ guarantee that you what price you want.

Comment: one last query. So to auto close someone must have bought those futures at negative price so close to the expiry.So they had to take the physical delivery ?

Comment: Possibly, but it's more likely that they already had a short position that they closed, or they took a chance that they could sell back the positions they bought for higher prices before the contract expired.